# Использование docker-образа с Testcontainers

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, docker

Всем привет. Для меня Testcontainers абсолютно новая тема, поэтому возник вопрос.
У меня есть приложение на Spring/Hibernate
У меня есть docker image (h2testbase) с кастомной mysql-базой (myTestDb) для тестов (она уже готовая с данными). Я запускаю этот образ в докере с -p 6161:3306.
В папке test/resources у меня лежит application.properties со следующим содержанием

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:6161/myTestDb?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow&&useSSL=false
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.cred=admin
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Прогоняю тесты с помощью mvn test - все работает.
Теперь я хочу запускать эти тесты с помощью Testcontainers.
Добавил в pom

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
   <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Я наследовал класс MySQLContainer

```
public class TestMySQL extends MySQLContainer {

    public TestMySQL() {
        super();
    }

    public TestMySQL(String dockerImageName) {
        super(dockerImageName);
    }

    @Override
    public String getDriverClassName() {
        return "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    }
}
```

так как сам MySQLContainer использует com.mysql.jdbc.Driver и maven не принимает его как deprecated.
В тесте я пишу

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        HibernateConfiguration.class,
        SecurityConfiguration.class,
        SecurityInitializer.class,
        ViewConfiguration.class,
        ViewInitializer.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ControllerServiceJTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static TestMySQL  container
            = new TestMySQL("h2testbase");

    @Autowired
    ControllerService controllerService;

    @Test
    public void stationPagination() {
        Map<String, Object> pag = controllerService.stationPagination(4);
        Assert.assertTrue(((List<Station>)pag.get("stations")).size() == 8);
    }

    @Test
    public void trainPagination() {
        Map<String, Object> pag = controllerService.trainPagination(1);
        Assert.assertTrue(((List<Train>)pag.get("trains")).size() == 20);
    }

    @Test
    public void switchHelper() {
        Assert.assertTrue(controllerService.stationSwitchHelper("BLUE").equals(URLs.REDIRECT_DASHSTATION + "/2"));
    }
}
```

И тут у меня ступор. Если я запущу mvn test, то через docker ps я вижу, что контейнер стартует (но на какие то левые порты типа 328хх), причем запускается несколько инстансов, но через некоторое время maven выдает следующее

```
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed
Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.RetryCountExceededException: Retry limit hit with exception
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Could not create/start container
Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.TimeoutException: org.rnorth.ducttape.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

Что делать дальше? Как указать создаваемому контейнеру на какой порт маппиться? Как передать ему параметры, которые прописаны в application.properties? Я не в состоянии найти ни одного примера кода, где использовался бы образ с готовой базой. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте метод `withPortBindings` и `withExposedPorts` при создании контейнера.

```
int hostPort = 6380;
int containerExposedPort = 6379;
Consumer<CreateContainerCmd> cmd = e -> e.withPortBindings(new PortBinding(Ports.Binding.bindPort(hostPort), new ExposedPort(containerExposedPort)));

GenericContainer redisContainer = new GenericContainer("redis:4.0.10")
                    .withExposedPorts(containerExposedPort)
                    .withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd);
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, но это, наверное, вторая часть проблемы. Первая часть - это эксепшены org.testcontainers.containers чью природу я совершенно не могу понять